# Tinymce not appeared complete in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have set tinymce with my program, but when I use this feature, I can't see complete such I see in tinymce website when I combine tinymce in my code igniter, this is the following code, that I used tinymce in my program  :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
</script>
```

Comment: "Complete" means? What are you seeing instead of editor? Editor with minimum icons?

Comment: yes, that's right .. and I can't save any picture when I try to save in database ... I can't display the uncomplete tinymce editor here because unallowed ..

Comment: Do you need to upload images via Tinymce? Default Tinymcedoesn't have option to upload images via Tinymce. You have to install additional plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I see in the comments that you are unable to upload images. TinyMCE provided a full script on how to load the full toolbar.

And @kumar_v, these plugins are ready-packed with the full js. You just need to activate it; no extra plugins are required.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation path>/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor moxiemanager"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ]
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
</form>
```